# Running python multiprocessing from outside of main script

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a a hierarchy of .py files calls as such:

main.py calls prepare.py calls vary.py

vary_values.py has a range(10) loop that is very computationally expensive. I would like to run these in parallel processes to take advantage of my 12 core cpu machine.

The problem is that running multiprocessing.Process() inside the vary_values.py file is not working for me (getting the freeze_support() error for due to not running it in **name** == '**main**')

How can I get just this piece to run in parallel without having everything all the way from main.py having to reload?

Example code:

**main.py**

```
import manything
from prepare import prepare_data

#### do many things here

data_list = prepare_data(old_data, vary_style)

#### do more things here
```

**prepare.py**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from vary import vary_features

def prepare_data(old_data, vary_style):
   #### do some things here
   changes = things we did above    
   array1 = old_data + changes
   data_list = vary_features(array1, vary_style)

   #### do more things here
   return data_list
```

**vary.py**

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

def add_noise(queue, array, mean):
    noise_vec = np.random.uniform(0, mean, size=array.shape)
    new_array = array + noise_vec        
    queue.put(new_array)

def vary_values(array1, mean):
    #### do some things here
    
    processes = []
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    array_list = []
    for i in range(array1.shape[0]):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=add_noise, args=(queue, array1[i], mean))
        processes.append(p)
        array_list.append(queue.get())
        
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    return array_list
```

This does not appear to work. All imports and lots of code in the main.py and prepare.py get rerun. Finally each process gets to the for loop again and it errors out.

What I would like happen is for ONLY the for loop to be spread across multiple processes. Is that possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what does not work, but I think you got several things wrong: 1) multiprocessing does not have to be started from the "main script", 2) there is no reason to start multiple processes to get the best performance - numpy can use all the available CPU power if needed, 3) I would not expect any of this to take advantage of your GPU. That does not happen so automatically.

Comment: `array_list` or `array_queue`?

Comment: @zvone Typo on the word GPU, I meant multi core CPU (now editted). As for core utilization, I am not seeing all cores being used during processing. As for needing to run in main script, Im not saying it needs to run from there, Im just showing the error I get when I run in 2 scripts deep.

Comment: @Leo You are not the first to think that if CPU is not at 100%, that the application is not as fast as it can be, but that is absolutely not correct. You should measure the performance not the load.